# Setting access level of T4 template parameters

Tags: c#, t4

I have a T4 template (ModelTemplate.tt) which inherits from a base template as follows:

```
<#@ template language="C#" inherits="BaseTextTemplate" #>
```

I have defined a parameter in BaseTextTemplate as follows:

```
<#@ parameter type="System.Boolean" name="Namespaced" #>
```

I would like to make use of this parameter in the derived class like this:

```
<# if (Namespaced) { #>
export class <#= Model.TsName#> {
<# } #>
<# else { #>
export class <#= Model.TsNamespacedName#> {
<# } #>
```

The problem is that doing this produces a error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0122  'BaseTextTemplate.Namespaced' is inaccessible due to its protection level

If we look at the code produced in BaseTextTemplate.cs, we see that the protection level of the parameter is indeed *private*.

```
/// <summary>
/// Access the Namespaced parameter of the template.
/// </summary>
private bool Namespaced
{
    get
    {
        return this._NamespacedField;
    }
}
```

I've searched all over to try and find how to change the access level of this parameter through an additional attribute. Does anyone know how this can be done?